# Why and how XAuth Twitter?

Tags: android, email, twitter

I am integrating twitter login in my android app using fabric kit and I just want to access user's email address after getting his/her access token. but i am not able to get and i am getting an error that Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. After searching for this issue i found a solution [http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/request-user-email-address.html][1]
and i found that if i want to get user's email address. I need to obtain xAuth access token. now my question is, what is xauth? why xauth? and when xauth?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your app have to be whitelisted by Twitter, you need to contact Twitter support service to know the process : support@crashlytics.com

i did this from fabric platform.

they will ask you about app description and why you need to collect emails, also prepare terms of service and privacy policy URL

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know about oAuth and xAuth?

Comment: no i have idea, they only asked me for `Your consumer key that you created on apps.twitter.com (not one automatically created by Fabric)
`

Comment: you can ask them for it

Comment: have fixed the problem, because after activating `Request email addresses from users` in permissions tab still i can't get email.

Comment: Where is this option in permission page?

Comment: "twitter support" added the option to my App